# iOS icons - can i just provide the 2x icon instead of 1x and 2x icons?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-icons

Will iOS automatically scale down 2x to make a 1x icon when running on a smaller device, if I just provide the 2x icon?

Note that I want to provide 2x icon, and not 1x icon (and expect iOS to scale up)

Comment: This has been asked before search on it. What happens on an older 1x iPad is it will load the full 2x image and render it appropriately, doing the downscaling in real time, but this adds processor and memory overhead to an already lower end system. Early next year you must provide 3x images.